# Connect to an Oracle db with ADODB using excel VBA

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, oracle11g

I'm using this connection string pattern with ADODB

```
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.ConnectionString = "User ID=USERNAME;Password=PW;Data Source=xxxxxxx.db.yyyy.com:port;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle; "
oConn.ConnectionTimeout = 30
oConn.Open
rs.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
```

and when I open the connection I'll get a run time error

> ORA-12504: TNS:listener wa not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

I have also tried using this connection string

```
"ODBC;DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient11g_home2};" & _
"DBQ=" & inputHost & ";UID=" & inputUser & ";PWD=" & inputPassword & ";" & _
"HOST=" & inputHost & ";PORT=1521;DB=" & inputHost & ";" & _
"DefaultIsolationLevel=READUNCOMMITTED"
```

and I get the run time error

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found an no default driver specified

Comment: In my limited experience this means that you need to edit the tnsnames.ora file to include or fix this connection.

Comment: may find help at http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Data Source=xxxxxxx.db.yyyy.com:port` is the problem. You should provide the TNS alias as defined in file `tnsnames.ora` instead of "ServerName.Domain:Port".

I do not know if OLEDB provider supports Easy Connect naming method. Did you specify like `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(tnsnames, ezconnect)` in your `sqlnet.ora` file?

Comment: So what kind of connection string patter should I use?

Comment: Ended up just having to use ConnectionString = _
"DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};" & _
"DBQ={{from tnsnames.ora}};UID=xxxxx;PWD=xxxx;"